# How to show/hide Telegram group messages only for group members, who carry out some action?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

We have a group in Telegram and want to hide group messages from members before they carry out some action, for example enter email. After member enter his email, he can see all group messages, else see nothing.

Is it possible with Telegram API or Telegram bot API?

Comment: You can't do this currently.

Comment: @Sean Thank you for your answear!

Comment: @Sean As I understand, when group member send message, it deliver to all group members (bot receive message too). Can I delete group message from certain chat members (not all), after they receive message?

Answer (score 1):

There is no message hiding ability in Telegram but there are some workarounds. You could create a bot that interact with user (e.g. gets and verifies his/her email) and then sends all "hidden" messages to him. Or just adds him to a private group (where no one can add other people except admin).